# Jenkins | Checkout SCM repository to a remote machine

Tags: jenkins

I got a jenkins job, which checkouts repository #1, builds the code and execute it. 
During execution, my code uses another code repository (#2), which located on a *remote server* and my code can access it easily.

I would like to have the **jenkins job checkout the latest code on both repositories #1 and #2, whereas repo #2 should be checked out into a remote server**. And I'd be happy to avoid scripts and git hooks.

Comment: Jenkins can do multiple repository checkouts.... what's the question/issue?

Comment: question is how you checkout the repo into a **remote** machine, and not into the slave/master which executes the job.

Comment: You can't, that goes against the whole master/slave principle. Only way is to script it yourself, using `ssh`, `plink`, or `psexec` with a specified remote machine

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Slav, you can use [Multiple SCM](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multiple+SCMs+Plugin) plugin which will allow you to checkout code on different SCM systems.

[image]